# TypeError: module.exports is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

My goal is to use the logger.js inside my app.js
I typed this from a tutorial but I have got different results than the tutorial.

-node-tutorial
--logger.js
--app.js

When I type `node app.js` in the console, I get this:

````
timbliefert@Tims-Air node-tutorial % node app.js
/Users/timbliefert/Developer/node-tutorial/logger.js:9
module.exports(log) = log;
       ^

TypeError: module.exports is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/timbliefert/Developer/node-tutorial/logger.js:9:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/timbliefert/Developer/node-tutorial/app.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)```
````

Comment: Try `module.exports.log = log`

Comment: If you don't see anything wrong with that line i would strongly recommend to start by learning javascript basics before getting into Node.js. Even if the module.exports was a function you would get another error like this `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` because you cannot assign a value to whatever the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

`module.exports` is an object by default and you haven't reassigned it to a function so you're not able to invoke it with parenthesis like a function. You can add properties to `module.exports` exactly like how you'd add them to an object in JS through assignment.

```js
module.exports.log = log;
```

Comment: I don't agree. module.exports can be a function, there's nothing wrong with that. This is ok `module.exports = function(){}` and this as well `module.exports()`

Comment: @Molda you're right. I misspoke. My answer definitely needs some revision.